# Как делаются такие слайдеры?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Подскажите как сделать такой слайдер? http://joxi.ru/p27x1ekTWb55wA

Comment: а что там, просто содержимое правой колонки меняется?

Answer (score 0):

Это делается обычным аккордеоном, только в вертикальном виде, можно даже на css + сделать наклон, а наполнение в каждый контейнер ставите какое вам нужно. Вот пример подобного аккордеона на css

> https://nisnom.com/veb-razrabotki/otzyvchivyj-gorizontalnyj-akkordeon-dlya-izobrazhenie-na-chistom-css/